# IBOutlet does not display its value in UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, iboutlet

I am building an iOS app using storyboards.I have implemented google maps in my app using swift and rest of the code is in objective C.

My scenario:

1.As shown in the diagram, when I click on the label in front of location ( in First view controller ) a modal segue opens a second view controller containing map.

2.In the map view controllers, when the user moves the map with touch, I'm getting address value in a label. ( similar to uber app )

3.After this , as soon as user presses done button on this controller, it gets back to the first view controller using custom segue and with the value of the location.

[image]

The problem is that, iboulet of this label is hidden in the UI and doesn’t display its value. But when I print this value in console, I am able to display the value.

Below is my code. Help is much appreciated.

First View Controller code written in swift:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _Locationlabel.text=_location;
    NSLog(@"location=%@",_Locationlabel.text);
}
```

Second View Controller code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "locationDone") {
            // pass data to next view

            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as Host;

            svc.location = self.addressLabel.text;
            println("location\(svc.location)");
        }
    }

    @IBAction func doTap(x:UIButton) {

     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});//This is intended to dismiss the Info sceen.
        println("pressed")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a custom segue to return to your first view controller. Segues always create a new instance of a view controller (unless you use an unwind segue).  In your first view controller, add this method:

```
- (IBAction)backFromMapView:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"and we are back");
    MapViewController* mvc = (MapViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
    NSLog(@"location %@", mvc.addressLabel.text);
}
```

Don't forget to `#import <YourProjectName>-Swift.h` so that `Host.m` will know about `MapViewController`.

Then you'd control drag from the `Done` button in your Map View Controller to the orange exit icon in the bar above the view controller in the Storyboard.  In the pop up, you'd select `backFromMapView` and voila, you're done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks vacawama for this detailed response. I would implement this and post an update. Thanks so much !

Comment: Hi @vacawama,  I was applying your method.

I have imported #import "MapViewController.swift" in Host.m
But when I apply - (IBAction) method, it is gives me an error at statement MapViewController* mvc = (MapViewController *)segue.sourceViewController; and error is
 Use of undeclared identifier 'MapViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Could you please help ?"

Comment: Is your project called Playo? If so, `#import Playo-Swift.h`

Comment: Thanks a lot @vacawama, the problem got solved by the method you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the location as a NSString strong property of your Host view controller OR Post a notification to your host view from Maps
And in the viewWillAppear of the Host,
First- NSLog the NSString and
Second- assign this string to the label as text

Comment: Hi Amisha, thanks for your quick response. 
                                                                            1. I have already used strong property for location:@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *location;

2. I tried applying second method which you suggested but I did not get value of location in viewWillAppear but instead, getting the value in viewDidLoad

Comment: Could you please let me know, where am I going wrong ?